# Publishing not working for some pages

Tags: 2011, publishing

I am publishing pages, 70% pages showing success and 30% have failure.
publishing service has following line in logs

> The number of render failures has exceeded its specified failure limit of 0.
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

some pages even don't have any component presentation added to them but still failing in publishing process.

Any idea what should i look into?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect one of your templates has an error stopping them from publishing. Publishing pages individually will allow you to find the problematic pages.

I typically run the pages template through Template Builder to step through the building blocks and find the error.

A good tip here is that if the page doesn't preview in the CMS, it likely won't publish.

Comment: yes some pages and not preview able, most probably problem is with page template but has to check because same page template works for other pages.

Comment: The same page template can definitely "break" on certain component presentations and metadata if it has a dependency on certain values or fails to check for fields before using them.

Comment: Yes the first line is the exact answer for my problem.There was issue with the CT added to page template.

Comment: glad to hear it helped @Aman

Answer (score 5):

If you double-click on the Publishing Task in the Publishing Queue, you can see some details of the publish transaction.  In the 'Processed Items' tab you should be able to find the particular items that failed, and which template they were using.
With that information you should be able to start investigating the problem in Template Builder.  Good luck :)

Answer (score 4):

If it is random failures and sometimes the same page succeeds and sometimes it fails, it could be that one of your publishers (if you have multiple publishers) is working while one of them is failing (maybe due to a Publishing event not firing correctly or some integration not setup the same on each machine).  I have also seen strange behavior with multiple publishers when the DB didn't have enough memory resources.

However, if it is failing always on the same page, I would go with the suggestions of others and investigate your template issues, and try first previewing the Component Presentation and then the entire Page.